# Simple Nancy Routes return 404

Tags: routes, nancy

I'm brand new to Nancy and going through some simple tutorials.
I'm trying to make a route in Nancy just to print out hello but returns 404 resource may have been removed... 
Here is what my code looks like

```
       public HelloModule (){
           Get["/hello"] = _ => "Hello World!" 
       }
}
```

Comment: Is your class public and does it inherit from NancyModule?

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to put that part of my class in the question but Yes I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by following this link https://auth0.com/blog/meet-nancy-a-lightweight-web-framework-for-dot-net/
And running Visual Studio as an Admin

Answer (score 0):

Question:
What do you get the 404 for:
 `http://<server>:port/hello` or `http://<server:port>/` ?

If it's the latter, you haven't defined that route.

Some more information would help.